# How to Connect oracle with node js and and express js in RESTFUL API?

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I already Connect MONGO DB and MYSQL on my RESTFul API using nodejs and express JS but don't be connect with oracl.
My Sql Connect Code is given bellow:

```
const mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'suedu_web'
}) 

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{

    if(!err)
    console.log('DB Connected Successfully')
    else
    console.log('DB Connected failed \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2))
})
```

Please give me Oracle Code.

Comment: See the posts from Oracle's JS evangelist: [Creating a REST API with Node.js and Oracle Database](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/)

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this:**

```
{
    user          : process.env.ORACLE_USER,
    password      : process.env.ORACLE_PASSWORD,
    connectString : "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID= ORCL)))"
  }
```

Comment: Most users connect via an Oracle net service name, not the very, very old SID syntax.  So the connect string would generally now be `"hostname/servicename"`

Comment: how do i connect using "SID" syntex , can you share one example of sid syntex  @ Christopher Jones

Answer (score 0):

You can use **oracledb** an Oracle Database Node.js™ Add-on

```
// This example uses Node 8's async/await syntax.

const oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

const mypw = ...  // set mypw to the hr schema password

async function run() {

  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(  {
      user          : "username_oracle",
      password      : "password_oracle",
      connectString : "localhost/XEPDB1"
    });

    const result = await connection.execute(
      'SELECT *
       FROM tableName'
    );
    console.log(result.rows);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: Dear Brother, I use Your code then show a error message how solve this issue.Please help me, my code and error given bellow:

Comment: I use this code but give me a error message, which is given bellow:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Here's the installation documentation: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md.  Looks like you have 32-bit Oracle 10.2 client libraries.  You need 11.2 (or later) client libraries.  You have a 64-bit Node.js, so you need 64-bit client libraries.

Comment: I use now 64 bit client library and define environment path in my pc, just tell me if any code write to define path in package.json file or some where